# How to bind dynamic values to the dropdown using ionic 2 & Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

[image]Hi im just trying to bind the  dynamic values to the dropdown but i confused how to bind it .

here is my json data

```
    [
  {
    "Name": "data1",  
    "sno": 3

  },
  {
    "Name": "data2",  
    "sno": 4
  },
  {
    "Name": "data3",  
    "sno": 5
  }
```

here im calling my dynamic data using providers

```
dropDown(){
var url1 ='http://xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx/info/Service1.svc/getData';
return this.http.get(url1).map(result=>{
  return result.json();
})
```

after that im calling this in a page by calling it in the constructor and  then using ngOnIt im initializing it

```
selectedValue: number;
  optionsList: Array<{ value: number, text: string}> = [];
```

the after declaring in the constructor

```
`ngOnInit(){



    this.optionsList = this.serv.dropDown().subscribe( response =>{

      console.log(response.json());

    });

  }`


 <ion-select>
    <ion-option *ngFor="let item of optionsList" value="{{item.value}}">{{item.text}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

but im getting error as **subscription is not assignable to the type** and how to get the selected value and text?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the returned value of subscribe which is an **Observable** to this.optionsList hence the error.
There are 2 ways to fix this:

1- you can use the **async** pipe to your ***ngFor** :

```
<ion-select>
    <ion-option *ngFor="let item of optionsList | async" value="{{item.value}}">
    {{item.text}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Also remove the callback in subscribe :

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.optionsList = this.serv.dropDown().subscribe();
}
```

2- Assigning the your property optionsList :

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.serv.dropDown().subscribe( response =>{
      this.optionsList = response;
    });

}
```

Note that I removed .json() function since the map function is already doing it for you.

Comment: change optionsList: Array<{ value: number, text: string}> = [];  to optionsList: any[];

Comment: i changed it and the the result im getting in the dropdown is nothing

Comment: Well, you will need to see what's in the response to see what's happening.
this.serv.dropDown().subscribe( response =>{
      console.log(response);   
      this.optionsList = response;
});